# using a function from a string of text PHP

Tags: php

I would like to know if it is possible to store the following
`ee()->session->userdata('group_id')` as a string in a variable.

Then to use it but as the function written inside.

Ultimately something that would look like

```
//request posted from somewhere
$request = "ee()->session->userdata('group_id')";
$myValue = $request // But here the function inside would be in place leaving the value of `$myValue` the id from the function and not the string.
```

I have another system that requires to utilise the foreign class `ee()` and i am hoping to create a bridge by posting a string and returning the return value and not the function string.

Comment: [eval();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) `Caution: The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.`

Comment: It is, but it's generally considered very bad practise, and can be highly dangerous if the string comes from user input, and if there's any errors in the string of code, then it's hard to debug

Comment: It cannot be overstated how bad of an idea this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). But be **very** careful with this function, as it is considered to be very harmful! Sanitize your strings!

Here is a quote from the PHP manual (linked above):

> **Caution**
>   The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: i had a suspicion it would be shady business. I cannot think of a better solution as yet but i guess i will have to. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you want, you can post another question asking how it could be done better and give an example what exaclty you need it for. Just as a suggestion.

Comment: I need only a few values so i will do it another way. the security issue wouldn't be too much hassle but the risk nonetheless isnt worth it for me. The idea came to mind of opening up a port for ease of use and although possible i think its not quite the great idea i had hoped for. I am glad to have learned about eval today though! many thanks